# sdo.gsfc.nasa.gov website offline?

Tags: observational-astronomy, the-sun

Is the NASA solar dynamics website offline? If not how can the daily sun 'movies' be downloaded from https://sdo.gsfc.nasa.gov/data/dailymov.php?

Comment: https://isitup.org/sdo.gsfc.nasa.gov  It's not just you.

Comment: Weekends are oftentimes times when scheduled outages for maintenance occur. For example, the entire Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange suite of sites was briefly shut down on Friday evening (New York time) on March 26. If this is the case (i.e., a planned outage for maintenance/upgrade), be patient; the site will be back. If this is not the case (i.e., an unscheduled outage), you might have to be even more patient. Staff are unhand for scheduled outages, and they try to make the outage be as brief as possible. OTOH, staff might not be unhand or even on call for a Sunday morning unscheduled outage.

Comment: @JamesK It's not just sdo.gsfc.nasa.gov. It appears to be gsfc.nasa.gov as a whole: https://isitup.org/gsfc.nasa.gov

Comment: It seems up at the moment https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYzVY.png